# Multiple radio buttons controlgroups in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, radio-button

I have the below html code

```
<fieldset id="a">
<input type="radio" name="choice1" value="1" radioatrr="0" class="myvalue1" /><label for="choice1">text 1</label> 
<input type="radio" name="choice2" value="2" radioatrr="0" class="myvalue2" /><label for="choice2">text 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice3" value="3" radioatrr="0" class="myvalue3" /><label for="choice3">text 3</label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="b">
<input type="radio" name="cb-choice1" value="4" radioatrr="1" class="myvalue4" /><label for="cb-choice1">text 4</label> 
<input type="radio" name="cb-choice2" value="5" radioatrr="1" class="myvalue5" /><label for="cb-choice2">text 5</label>
</fieldset>
```

I want if choice2 is checked and one of cb-choice1 or cb-choice2 then the received value is the value of cb-... choice (4 or 5) if choice2 is checked and no cb-... is checked then the received value is 2.

How can I do this?

I try this

```
$("input:checked").each(function(i) {
   if (($(this).attr("radioatrr") == 0)) {
      alert(($(this).attr("value"));
   }
})
```

but can not working as I want

Comment: Did you try anything with js? If you did can you share?

Comment: And also your question is not clear. Include expected result

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this tutorial from W3 to help you out:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_radio_value.asp

**In regards to your problem, you can hook in this function:**

```
function handleRadioSelection() {
    if(document.getElementByName('choice2').checked) {
        if (document.getElementByName('cb-choice1').checked) {
            return document.getElementByName('cb-choice1').value
        } else if (document.getElementByName('cb-choice2').checked) {
            return document.getElementByName('cb-choice2').value
        } else {
            return document.getElementByName('choice2').value
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a hidden input field to capture the value that you want, you can change it to anything else. I've also modified the radio buttons into two groups, as from reading the question/requirements I think that's how it should be setup.

```js
$("#submit").click(function() {
  //capture group 1 and group 2 value that's checked
  var val1 = $('input[name=choice]:checked').val();
  var val2 = $('input[name=choice2]:checked').val();
  
  //capture the input object with the desired value
  var sendVal = $('input[name=myval]');
  
  //reset value to 0 as this happens on click, incase value gets changed
  sendVal.val(0);
  
  //if group 1 is 2 and there is a value selected in group2
  if(val1==2&&val2 != undefined){
    sendVal.val(val2);
    
  //if group 1 is 2 and group 2 is not selected
  }else if(val1==2&&val2 == undefined){
    sendVal.val(val1);
  }
  
  //showing value to be sent in an alert
  alert(sendVal.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Group 1</h2>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="1" class="myvalue1" /><label for="choice1">text 1</label> 
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="2" class="myvalue2" /><label for="choice2">text 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="3" class="myvalue3" /><label for="choice3">text 3</label>

<h2>Group 2</h2>
<input type="radio" name="choice2" value="4" class="myvalue4" /><label for="cb-choice1">text 4</label> 
<input type="radio" name="choice2" value="5" class="myvalue5" /><label for="cb-choice2">text 5</label>

<input type="hidden"name="myval" value="0">
<br/>
<button id="submit">submit</button>
```